# update VSTS user reference without loosing data

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

we are currently trying to gather our different teams service account (VSTS) on our Azure Enterprise Agreement and align their authentication methods: moving from personal account (MSA) to AAD + guest (not that simple...).

Unfortunately, many users have personal accounts (MSA) with different email domains then in AAD (legacy subsidiary).

- in VSTS : firstname.lastname@companyB.com
- in AAD : firstname.lastname@companyA.com

is there a way (powershell, API (only GET access), Microsoft premiere ticket) for one user from firstname.lastname@companyB.com to firstname.lastname@companyA.com without loosing all related contents (work item, git commit, build/release favorites, etc etc etc)

Comment: Does Change account owner for Visual Studio Team Services or Change Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant meet your requirement? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-azure-active-directory-team-services-account

Comment: VTST instance isn't currently associated to an AAD. But connect is the goal. the issue is that for various reasons, current signin bob@companyB.com (MSA) will then signin with bob@companyA.com (AAD) losing contents associated to bob@compagnyB.com (according to my understanding and various articles, including your second link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discussed with VSTS Microsoft Support and there is a way to perform it, but not by myself.

Our users will create visual studio account through visualstudio.com firstname.lastname@companyA.com (destination) connecting with 'work or school'.

Then Microsoft will run after the connection to AAD a mapping script moving references of firstname.lastname@companyB.com to firstname.lastname@companyA.com.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this as far as I know since it's not just a simple account change, it is related to a lot of things like identities, the history of work items and version control. The workaround for your scenario is adding these users to your AAD with Microsoft Account Email address. Refer to this link for more information: [Team Services: Access with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs).

> **What happens to current users?**
>
> Your work in Team Services is associated with your sign-in address.
>   After your Team Services account is connected to your directory, users
>   will continue working seamlessly if their sign-in addresses appear in
>   the connected directory. If they don't, you'll have to add those users
>   to your directory. Your organization might have policies about adding
>   users to the directory, so find out more first.